# cos giving out the wrong value

Tags: c++, trigonometry

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include "boost/math/constants/constants.hpp"
const double pi = boost::math::constants::pi<double>();

int main() {
    double x = 2;
    double y = 1;
    double angle = 90; //in degrees
    double rad { angle * pi / 180 }; //converting to rads
    std::cout << "rad: " << rad << std::endl; //1.5708 - OK
    double c = cos( rad );
    std::cout << "cos(rad): " << c << std::endl; //6.12303e-017 - Huh? Should be ~ -3.2051033e-9
    double s = sin( rad );
    std::cout << "sin(rad): " << s << std::endl; //1 - OK
    x = x * c - y * s;
    y = x * s + y * c;
    std::cout << "(" << x << "," << y << ")" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So this is weird, I'm trying to do a rotation but the `cos` is giving me the wrong value. It should be something near to `-3.2051033e-9` but I end up with `6.12303e-017`. I've converted my angle to radians and it checks out. `sin( rad )` returns the correct value as well. 
What gives?

Edit:
The code has an error but not related to the question. On `y = x * s + y * c;` the x should refer to the the value declared at the top but as the previous equation overrides that value the `y` at the end would be wrong.

Thanks for the clarification of exponents. I got a bit confused.

Comment: cos(90°) should be (very close to, what with floating point inaccuracy) 0, as indeed it is. Why do you think `-3.2e-9` would be more correct than `6.1e-17`?

Comment: When you think a standard library mathematical function is wrong, _you_ are wrong.

Comment: Double precision math produces up to 15 significant digits.  It doesn't make any sense to expect -3E-9 as the approximation for the ideal value (0.0), it isn't close enough.  6E-17 is good.  Maybe you are used to seeing single precision results.

Comment: On a [side note](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/intel-underestimates-error-bounds-by-1-3-quintillion/) intel's `fcos` and `fsin` intrinsics are horrible... try setting your application to build with SSE2 and see if the issue goes away.

Comment: @Jefffrey Interesting, what's the nature of the bug?

Comment: @sashoalm It's not `constexpr`. :P

Comment: *where* did you obtain your result of `-3.2051033e-9`?

Comment: @hometoast from the os' calculator when I was going through the calcs manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cos(90)` (degrees) is approximately zero, as in `0.0`. Worrying about getting a number back that is `e-17` vs `e-9` is not meaningful, they are both basically zero.

How close it the result *actually* is depends on how they represented `pi`, `90.0`, `180.0`, and the implementation of the `cos` function in `math.h`.

Comment: Frankly, a rounding error of `-3.2e-9` would be astonishingly large for this calculation with (64-bit) `double`s. It'd make sense in a calculation with (32-bit) `float`s.

Comment: @Wintermute what about 90000 degrees? both single and double gives ridiculous errors.

Comment: cos(90000°) is not OP's calculation (and `-3.2e-9` would still be an astonishingly large rounding error for it).

Answer (score 2):

> It should be something near to -3.2051033e-9 but I end up with 6.12303e-017.

I don't know why you think it "should be -3.2051033e-9" because `cos(90º)` is zero, and `-0.0000000032051033` is well outside of the margin of error of your calculations,

The value you're getting, `0.0000000000000000612303` is *zero*, and therefore *correct*, within the margin of error of your calculations.

Answer (score 0):

There is no error in your code..

In the cos function (cos ), return value is a real. And here is some examples;

```
(cos -1) returns 0.540302
(cos 0.0) returns 1.0
(cos (* pi 0.5)) returns 6.12303e-017 which is practically equal to **0**
```

And also you can check it with **inverse** cos with **cos(6.12303e-017)** and you will see it is *90* degree